# End parent process with fork avoiding become zombie

Tags: c, linux, fork, ipc

I'm trying to implement some code in C project to avoid the use of `pclose` that is blocking my project. Now I'm using `fork()` + `exec()` instead but I have a problem. I've created a pipe to interconnect the two processes. In the child process I'm calling `exec()` to execute a script that reads an input and I'm catching the output of the script in the parent process.

The problem is that scripts get blocked randomly and I don't want this to block my program. When the parent process ends reading the output, it has finished without a `wait()` to avoid keep waiting infinitely but because of this the child process become a zombie process.

Here is my code:

```
int    pipefd[2];
        int nbytes = 0;

        signal(SIGCHLD, kill_child);

        pipe(pipefd);
        if (vfork() == 0)
        {
                close(pipefd[0]);
                dup2(pipefd[1], 1);
                close(pipefd[1]);
                execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", cpCommand, NULL);
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        else
        {
                close(pipefd[1]);
                while ((nbytes = read(pipefd[0], output, sizeof(output))) > 0)
                {
                        write(1, output, nbytes);
                }
                close(pipefd[1]);
        }
        strcpy(cpOutput, output);


void kill_child(int sig_num)
{
        wait();
}
```

What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: Do you mean that your `read` call in the parent blocks? Make the pipe non-blocking then. Or do you mean that the `wait` call blocks? Then use e.g. `waitpid` with the `WNOHANG` flag.

Comment: _All_ processes become zombies at some point. If the parent process outlives the child, the child will be a zombie state until an explicit `wait` call is made. If the parent terminates, while the child still runs on (orphaned), it'll get adopted by the `init` process. The kernel will kill all child processes in the end (worst case: when you reboot/shutdown the system), once in a while, `init` will reap zombie processes anyways

Comment: Ok, now I'm thinking to poll with waitpid in the parent process and after a timeout kill the child process if it don't finish..

Comment: I think that I have a problem with execl because I have put a printf after it and It never shows but the scripts ends..

Comment: The members of the `exec*()` family of functions only return in case execution of their argument failed, else they do not return, so any statement being put after them will never execute. See `man 3 exec`for details.

Comment: The use of `vfork` is pretty suspect too.

Comment: I have read the linux man page of exec as you suggested and I see that only returns un case of error, this means that on a wright execution this process is always going to become zombie?, is there any way to avoid this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can double fork:

```
 pid_t pid = fork();
 if (pid == 0) {
      pid = fork();
      if (pid == 0) {
           ...
           execl(...);
      }
      _exit(0);
 }

 waitpid(pid, ...);

 read(...);
```

Perhaps, `setsid()` should be called in the child and/or `SIGHUP` be ignored.

Code above detaches the second child (your `execl()`) from main program and init will reap it.

You might want to play with some control pipes to signal errors (`execl()` fails) to the main process.

Comment: @downvoters: it would be really nice when you would justify your actions